# Tailwind css a specific style for publication page

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

I am making my page using Tailwind CSS and I stuck on the publication page. I want something like this.
[image]

I tried to do with Tailwind CSS but did not able to get it fully.

```js
const abstractButton = document.getElementById('abstract-button');
const closeButton = document.getElementById('close-button');
const abstractPopup = document.getElementById('abstract-popup');

abstractButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    abstractPopup.classList.remove('hidden');
});

closeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    abstractPopup.classList.add('hidden');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="flex flex-col h-screen">    
    <div class="flex flex-row justify-center items-center my-4">
    <div class="mr-8 h-60 w-60">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Journal of Algebra" class="w-36 h-auto">
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="mb-4 text-lg">
            The image of polynomials and Waring type problems on upper triangular matrix algebras
        </p>
        <p class="mb-4">
            <span class="authors">Authors: </span><strong>Sachchidanand Prasad</strong>, Saikat Panja and Navnath Daundkar
        </p>
        <div class="flex space-x-4 items-center my-2">
            <div class="border rounded-lg border-gray-600 p-1">
            <a href="https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.08827" target="_blank" class="text-blue-500 hover:text-blue-800">arXiv</a>
            </div>
            <div class="border rounded-lg border-gray-600 p-1">
            <a href="link-to-journal" target="_blank" class="text-blue-500 hover:text-blue-800">Journal</a>
            </div>
            <div class="border rounded-lg border-gray-600 p-1">
            <a href="link-to-pdf" target="_blank" class="text-blue-500 hover:text-blue-800">PDF</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="mt-4 bg-blue-500 text-white py-2 px-4 rounded hover:bg-blue-700" id="abstract-button">Abstract</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Abstract Popup -->
    <div id="abstract-popup" class="fixed inset-0 flex items-center justify-center hidden">
    <div class="absolute bg-white rounded-lg p-8 w-1/2">
        <h2 class="text-xl font-bold mb-4">Abstract</h2>
        <p class="text-gray-800">
        This is the abstract of your paper. It provides a concise summary of your research, highlighting the main objectives, methods, and findings. You can customize this section with your own abstract content.
        </p>
        <button class="mt-6 bg-blue-500 text-white py-2 px-4 rounded hover:bg-blue-700" id="close-button">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are the following problems that I am facing:

1. The image size is not constant, that is, when the title of the publication is small, the image is bigger and when it is large, then the image size is small.
2. I am not getting the year like this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: "I am not getting the year like this." – It does not seem you have included the markup for the year in your example. Could you update your example code with the year included please?

Comment: Try adding `shrink-0` to the left column to keep the size fixed.

Comment: @Wongjn I do not know how to do that, this is why I have just written as a text.

Comment: @stickyuser `shrink-0` is not working.